# How to use composite unique trigger in postgres

Tags: postgresql

how to use composite Unique using trigger I have one column user_id and service_id i want to restrict duplicate records in user_id according to service_id means ie for service_id=1  all records should be unique in user_id 
all by trigger

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a trigger for this.   A Unique constraint on multiple columns would do it.

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD UNIQUE (service_id, user_id);
```

Docs at:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html

Comment: I know this but i have to us it in trigger

Comment: I want unique for only for one service constraint on multiple columns will restrict all services